# Keras, how to merge models without losing weights?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Consider this type of setup:

```
model1 = keras.Model(...)
model2 = keras.Model(...)
A = keras.Input(...)
B = model1(A)
C = model2(B)
model3 = keras.Model(A,C)
model3.compile(...)
```

This all works fine if I'm starting from scratch and proceed to train my composite model, but how can I glue models together like this without the weights being reset?  For example, if one or both of model1 and model2 have pretty good weights already (but I still want to be able to continue training)?

Comment: Weights are not reset in this case, what makes you think they are?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken.  Are the weights initialized when the model is created then?